# View renders correctly in browser but tests fail on helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rspec, helper

I have a simple view and a helper that defines the title. Everything works fine if I pull up the view in the browser, but the rspec tests fail. Here's what I have:

Here are my tests:

```
describe PagesController do
  render_views

  before(:each) do
    @base_title = "RoR Sample App"
  end

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title",
                                    :content => @base_title + " | Home")
    end
  end
end
```

The Pages Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = "Home"
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
end
```

The helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # Return a title on a per-page basis.
  def title
    base_title = "RoR22 Sample App"
    if @title.nil?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
    end
  end
end
```

And the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

It all renders properly in the browser, but the tests fail when it gets to `<%= title %>` line.

```
 1) PagesController GET 'home' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'home'
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `title' for #<#<Class:0xabf0b1c>:0xabeec18>
     # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:4:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___418990135_90147100_123793781'
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with spork. You can use this workaround in your prefork block:

```
Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application, :reload_routes!)
Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to more info about this known issue please?

Comment: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/94
https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/issues/37
Great resources here: https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujitsu
and here: http://my.rails-royce.org/2012/01/14/reloading-models-in-rails-3-1-when-usign-spork-and-cache_classes-true/

Perhaps 'issue' was a strong word. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's your `application.html.erb`.  It can't see that method in the `PagesHelper`, you need to put that method in your `ApplicationHelper`.  Only the views rendered by your `PagesController` can see `PagesHelper`.  And it's a good idea to explicitly add `return` in your helpers.

Comment: I get the same error when I put it in ApplicationHelper. Do I have to explicitly tell rspec to look there?

Comment: explicitly add `return` in your statement as well, updated answer

Comment: right, that's a good point and all. Any thoughts about why it can't see the `ApplicationHelper` either?

Answer (score 0):

It ends up the problem is that I was using the `Spork` gem to speed up my testing and for whatever reason `spork` wasn't registering that the `ApplicationHelper` had changed.

The solution was simply to reboot the `spork` gem and rerun the tests.

Comment: What do you mean by 'rebooting' spork exactly? How do I do this?

Comment: If you started spork with a command like `spork rspec --bootstrap`, then kill that process (CTRL+C) and start it again